# Problem with permissions on a linux executable

Tags: linux, permissions, user-controls

I have User with name "commander" in my system which doesnt have any permissions to passwd command and I have other users in my system that represent soldiers with names: (fighter01, fighter02, fighter03, fighter04...).

So what I want to do is when I am logged in as a commander I would be able to reset passwords (passwd  command) only for those users of soldiers (fighter01, fighter02...) and for other users I would be able to do that.

I tried to use awk command but I dont really know how it helps me.
Thought about using setfacl but this command works only for the files.

Can you please explain to me how do I do it?

Comment: for other users I would not* be able to do that.

Comment: As far as I know this type of `passwd` scoping is not supported out-of-box on linux. Generally speaking you are either a normal user and can change your own password or you are admin and can change everyone's password. I imagine that you might be able to write a small wrapper around `passwd` that might allow for this but that would likely still require the  "command" to have admin access so would probably not be much better.

Comment: I was thinking about something like what if in /etc/passwd I go through the usernames and if I find the right username which starts with fighter then I would give the permissions to the commander to run command passwd

Comment: That should be *fine*. Just understand that the commander user will still need admin access to change the other user's passwords so this is only slightly better than making each command an admin. IIRC You might be able to at least mitigate this by playing with "set uids"